# Angular : Why does sort only work on first Mat Table?

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material2

Why is it that the sort functionality advertised here : https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

fails as soon as you add a second table to display the second half of your data? :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vg9gn-q1back?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material have brought their own support to stickying headers which should in theory solve my issue once it releases : https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11483

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are assigning an instance of `MatSort` to your datasource. The `sort` member will be the first instance of `MatSort` directive that angular can find in the template.

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; //1st sort directive

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Since you are sharing the datasource between the 2 tables, only the first one is used.

You cannot share your datasource across tables in you want to do operations such as sorting, filtering,..

The solution is to have one datasource per table.

Comment: thanks that's a good answer that really explains alot ....and that's the last thing I wanted to hear. from what I hear if I were to seperate the datasource into two then the sorting would no longer affect both tables. So you're telling me Angular and Material want to screw it's users over functionality wise? why? Why can't we have pinned columns which they ONLY allow you to accomplish via two tables, sorting AND filtering? now I have to choose? this is the absolute worst.